# How many transactions per second can Kovan or Rinkeby Network handle?

Tags: rinkeby, kovan

Now, Ethereum can handle only 8-12 transactions per second by using PoW Consensus.
I know that Kovan and Rinkeby is using PoA Consensus. PoA is lightweight than PoW. So how many transactions per second can Kovan or Rinkeby Network handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Kovan and Rinkeby have a gas limit of ~7 million, which is about 330 regular ETH transfers per block (21,000 gas each). Kovan has a ~4 second blocktime and Rinkeby has a ~15 second blocktime, so the tx/s for Kovan is ~80 and for Rinkeby is ~20. These are just based on the max gas/block. Since they are both PoA, they might impose their own artificial limits though.

Note that the Ethereum mainnet actually has the capability of ~20 tx/s if all the tx were regular ETH transfers.